# Running detex on bibtex files, but keep "{ }" around entire articles

Tags: bibtex, detex

I have a bibtex file with entries like

```
@article{Alesse.2003,
 author = {Alesse, Francesca},
 year = {2003},
 title = {Il tema dell'emanazione ({\dq}aporroia{\dq}) nella letteratura astrologica e non astrologica tra I sec. a.C. e II d.C.},
 pages = {117–133},
 volume = 5,
 journal = {MHNH: Revista internacional de investigaci{\'o}n sobre magia y astrolog{\'i}a antiguas}
}
```

and I want to detex this, but keep the outermost "{}", so it should look like

```
@article{Alesse.2003,
 author = Alesse, Francesca,
 year = 2003,
 title = Il tema dell'emanazione (aporroia) nella letteratura astrologica e non astrologica tra I sec. a.C. e II d.C.,
 pages = 117–133,
 volume = 5,
 journal = MHNH: Revista internacional de investigacion sobre magia y astrologia antiguas
}
```

By default, detex removes all curly braces. How can I keep it from removing the outermost pair?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! I am unsure, but this could be a little bit off-topic. No questions are tagged `detex` so far.

Comment: Thanks! I was kind of hoping this can be achieved with detex alone, avoiding the use of another shell script.

Comment: I don't think `detex` is designed to do this. I'm not sure it's really meant to do anything "`.bib`"-related, in fact. Anyway, if everything is on its own line, as in your above example, a little `sed` or `awk` should work. How much more complicated are the entry fields than what you've shown here?

Comment: I'm certain that every entry is on its own line. The only difference is that there are a few other citation types beside article, like lecture or inproceedings. I'm trying to figure out regular expressions right now...

Comment: What's the purpose? I can't see any.

Comment: It has more purpose than posting comments not leading to any solution or any clue.

Comment: I figured out a solution using awk, detex is not intended for this purpose as suggested by jon. So I'm closing this. Thanks to all of you!

Comment: Seems not to be possible with detex.

Comment: @WurzelPi Knowing what your aim is can help in finding a solution.

Comment: It has to run through an existing, seemingly not very good parser to create metadata for a website. I'm employed as a student 5hrs/week and have other things to do, so rewriting the parser is currently not an option.

Comment: To be more precise, and if you allow for some complaining, the medieval history guys are using Citavi for their database, which is really restrictive in matters of exporting. We want to import some of this data into a modded version of aigaion, a web based bibliography system that is no longer developed or supported and that is modded in a way that it generates metadata for the regular website. The people that were responsible before are long gone. The mods are not documented very well, too. By now, I figured out importing in mentioned format would work. Also, sorry for the harsh tone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it's apparently not possible with Detex here's another approach -- **test it on a copy of your data**:

```
sed 's/^\([^{]*\){\(.*\)}\([^}]*\)$/\1\2\3/' copy_of_my.bib > another_copy_of_my.bib
```

This uses the Unix/GNU/Linux etc. `sed` tool to match a whole line (`^` matches the start and `$` the end) consisting of:

- A group of 0 or more characters other than open-curly-bracket -- `[^{]*` -- (where the `\(`...`\)` saves the matched text for later use as `\1`), followed by:
- an open-curly-bracket, followed by:
- a group of 0 or more characters other than close-curly-bracket -- `[^}]` -- again captured by `\(`...`\)` as `\2`.  This is followed by:
- a close-curly-bracket, then
- a group of 0 or more characters other than close-curly-bracket -- `[^}]*`, captured as `\3` and the end of the line (because of the `$`).

This means that the 3 capturing groups `\1\2\3` contain everything except the outermost matched pair of curly brackets on a line. So constructions such as `title = {{CamelCase} Title},` will survive as `title = {CamelCase} Title,`. This is thanks to greedy matching.  The `@article{key,}` line fails the match because it doesn't have a close-curly-bracket in it, and is passed to the output unchanged.  Where you want to remove this sort of construction and the `{\dq}`s in your source data (not mentioned in the text of your question, I recommend writing some more sed scripts -- detex doesn't know about bibtex.  Another way would be to pipe *each line* of sed's output from the script above through detex.

If you omit everything after the `>` output will be to screen -- that's just standard redirection.  The input is `copy_of_my.bib` for testing.

This seems to work OK even if you have the closing `}` on the last line of the record, in my tests, but I don't recommend this -- **test it first** if your file is structured like that.  It's also happy with indentation.

Note: `sed` uses slightly different syntax (in most regex engines you wont need a `\` before a `(` or `)`, for example). There are tools for commandline regexes on windows (if nothing else I'm pretty certain `sed` is built in to cygwin).

Also note that using regexes to match brackets in programming is generally reckoned to be a *bad idea*; we can only get away with it here (just) because bibtex is quite strict with its line structure.

Finally **don't write the output over the input** unless/until you're confident in how it works.